# How to keep printing untill you hit a button in c

Tags: c

I am new to c programming
I am working on a code which requires the program to keep running until i hit a specific key(not with enter but with just one button)

For example-

My code keeps on printing "Hello World"

```
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
.
.
.
```

As soon as i press a button say the letter A then the program should stop.

I tried using `getch();`
But it will pause the code until i hit a character and then goes to the next line.
How do i overcome this.
Can someone please help.

Comment: read about [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) library

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `GetKeyState()` from `winuser.h`. Here's a [link][1] to help you understand.

Though you shouldn't be dealing with key presses in the console.

EDIT:

'GetKeyState()' only works with the WIN32 API.

Use getch.
A demonstation below-

````
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <clib.h>//sorry for the long list of headers(I was originally using this code for some big project)
char q;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("enter value-");
    while(1){
if(kbhit()){

q=getch();
if(int(q)==115){  //I'm using 's' for the keypress

    printf("\nSuccess");

}
else{

    printf("\nYou didn't press s");

}
}



    }

















while(!kbhit()); //pauses console
return 0;

}```
````

Comment: I tried this. But since i am using Ubuntu , my gcc cannot find conio.h ,  kbhit(). This is why i tried using curses.h and getch() but am unable to figure out a solution. Can you help me using curses.h library?